# I broke Firefox with bad changes in 'about:config', how do I restore the defaults?

Tags: 16.04, firefox, configuration, settings, reset

I have been experimenting with the `about:config` settings of Firefox 47.0 on my new Xenial installation. This unfortunately has left Firefox broken.

I have read how to search through `about:config` to reset all of my bad settings but I would prefer to completely *reset to defaults*.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox can be easily reset to defaults after injudicious alterations in `about:config` by following these steps:

1. Close Firefox completely
2. Open the folder `~/.mozilla/firefox/< Profile Name >/`, the `< Profile Name >` folder will most usually be named something like this:

[image]

3. Within that folder rename the file `prefs.js` to `prefs.js_bak` by right clicking on the file and selecting 'Rename...'. Again a screenshot to demonstrate the exact location:

[image]

4. Reopen Firefox and resolve never to break it again :)

**References:**

- [Mozilla Zine: Profile folder - Firefox](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox)
- [Mozilla Xine: Resetting preferences](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Resetting_preferences)

Answer (score 1):

First, you can try reseting the settings of firefox.
If it doesn't work, remove firefox completely using the command  :

```
sudo apt-get purge firefox
```

Then try reinstalling it using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```